# one sentence from the article on history

Tags: grammar

*Without "normalizing" the Great Purge or denying its unprecedented character and still unexplained origins, we are now in a position to view it in a broader historical perspective than was possible earlier; perceiving more clearly its place in the larger patterns of Russian and world history.*

Will you be so kind and explain to me why is not used in the above sentence "it" in this part:  *…than (it = subject) was possible earlier.*

Comment: Here is an unorthodox way I use to understand this kind of structure. Because it's unorthodox, I'll post it here rather than as an answer. The basic idea is when using *than*, we need to delete the shared part. For example, *"She runs [fast]. He can run [less fast]."* would become *"She runs **faster than** he can run."* The *less fast* must be deleted. In other words, *"She runs faster than he can run \*fast,"* is ungrammatical. (We can also include *run* into the shared part and get: *She runs faster than he can.*)

Comment: Similarly, we can analyze your example like this: *We can view it in [a broad perspective]. [A less broad perspective] was possible. --> We can view it in **a broader perspective than** was possible.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of "broader than was possible earlier" as an adjectival phrase modifying "historical perspective".

The same can be done with adverbial comparisons: You drove *faster than was allowed*, so you got a speeding ticket.